# Issue with For Loop in Constraint Using PyMProg Package

Tags: python, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I'm using the PyMathProg package. Documentation can be found here: http://pymprog.sourceforge.net/.

I've created a basic MIP program, but I'm running into a syntax issue with my constraints. I followed the dive-in tutorial in the documentation above and then modified.

```
from pymprog import * 

a = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
b = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
c = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
d = (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50)
s = (2, 8, 5, 4, 6, 1, 4, 3, 8, 10)

begin('example')

verbose(True)

x = var('x', 10, kind=bool)

maximize(sum(s[i]*x[i] for i in range(10)))

for i in range(10):
    sum(x[i]) == 5
    sum(a[i]*x[i]) >= 5
    sum(b[i]*x[i]) >= 250
    sum(c[i]*x[i]) >= 15
    sum(d[i]*x[i]) >= 90

solve()
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error below.

```
sum(x[i]) == 5
TypeError: '_var' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You could do that w/a, b, c, d, or s, because those are tuples, but x isn't something you can iterate over (sum is basically looping over x, applying your condition).  Even in the documentation they don't attempt to do this.  Even still, x is boolean, which means it's going to be 0 or 1, so it will never be == 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using sum, which is fine. It takes a list and adds them up

```
sum([1,2,3])
6
```

The problem is, you're passing into it something that isn't a list, `x[i]` and the others, they are single elements.

This is why it says `TypeError: '_var' object is not iterable`. Because you are passing in elements from the list x, that is created by using `var`.

I thing what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
from pymprog import *

a = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
b = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
c = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
d = (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50)
s = (2, 8, 5, 4, 6, 1, 4, 3, 8, 10)

begin('example')

verbose(True)

x = var('x', 10, kind=bool)

maximize(sum(s[i]*x[i] for i in range(10)))

for i in range(10):
    sum(x[j+i] for j in range(3)) == 5
    sum(a[i]*x[j] for j in range(3)) >= 5
    sum(b[i]*x[j] for j in range(3)) >= 250
    sum(c[i]*x[j] for j in range(3)) >= 15
    sum(d[i]*x[j] for j in range(3)) >= 90

solve()
```

You can see where I've changed the second `[i]` to a `[j]` and added a `for j in range (3)`. That means a list will be created inside that `sum` call.

You can run that and see how close it is to what you're trying to do, as I'm not completely sure myself.